# if/elif not functioning with print

Tags: python

I'm doing a prject in school and it consists on small challenges, but on this, once the answer is inputted, it doesn't display anything:

```
sleepHours=float(input("how many hours of sleep did you have last night?")) 
if sleepHours == 0-4:

    print ("back to bed!")

elif sleepHours == 5-7:

    print ("not bad...")

else:

    print ("Well Done!")
```

Comment: It works just fine when you enter `-4` or `-2`.

Comment: You're asking it if sleepHours = -4 or -2.

Comment: That's because `0-4` is calculated first, which is `-4`, and `5-7` is `-2`. Those are not ranges of values.

Comment: Well, it does print `Well Done!` for me.

Answer (score 2):

comparing with float does not work the way you think it does...

your code should be

```
if 0 <= sleepHours <= 4:
    ...
```

what your code effectively does is compare `sleepHours` to `0-4` which is `-4`. (and similar for the second comparison).

Answer (score 0):

```
sleepHours=float(input("how many hours of sleep did you have last night?"))

if 0 <= sleepHours <= 4:
    print ("back to bed!")
elif 5 <= sleepHours <= 7:
    print ("not bad...")
else:
    print ("Well Done!")
```

Comment: Chaining comparisons (`0 <= sleepHours <= 4`) is more idiomatic than two separate comparisons joined by `and`.

Comment: Thanks, i also don't get why
 food = float(input("How much do you spend on lunchtime food in an average day? "))
total price = food * 5
print ("This means that in a week you will spend ", total)

doesnt work

Comment: food = float(input("How much do you spend on lunchtime food in an average day? "))
total_price = food * 5
print ("This means that in a week you will spend {}".format(total_price))

Comment: @chepner Thanks, I'm taking your advice

Comment: `How much do you spend on lunchtime food in an average day? 23
This means that in a week you will spend 115.0
`